# Using uigetdir as callback for a pushbutton, crashes due to weird, invalid arguments

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I am trying to create a simple "browse" button on a Matlab (R2016a) GUI.
My code is something like:

```
hd = dialog;
hb = uicontrol('parent',hd,'style','pushbutton','string','browse',...
'callback',@uigetdir);
```

The callback function `uigetdir` has 2 optional arguments `STARTPATH, TITLE`. In principle I could pass these on my callback by concatenating them with the function handle on a cell array, such as

```
hd = dialog;
hb = uicontrol('parent',hd,'style','pushbutton','string','browse',...
'callback',{@uigetdir,'myStartPath','myTitle');
```

Whether my browse button calls `uigetdir` with or without the optional arguments, it will crash. Different errors, same reason: `uicontrol` decides to include 2 uncalled-for, weird variables (containing UI properties) as arguments to the callback function, and `uigetdir` doesn't know what to do with them.

Does this mean I cannot use `uigetdir` (or pretty much any other built in function) as a callback function in a GUI? There must be a solution besides writing a custom function, no?

Comment: I suggest reading [the documentation for callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html#f16-1001315)

Comment: Really? From the documentation: "The function definition must define two input arguments, `hObject` and `callbackdata`. Handle Graphics® automatically passes `hObject` and `callbackdata` when it calls the function."

Comment: Also from the documentation: "Note: If you want to use an existing function that does not support the `hObject` and `callbackdata` arguments, then you can specify it as an anonymous function. For example, `uicontrol('Style','slider','Callback',@(hObject,callbackdata)myfunction(x));`"

Comment: @excaza The link and highlighted text are indeed helpful; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default all `uicontrol` objects are passed two input arguments:

- The `uicontrol` handle itself
- An object containing information specific to the event.

When you define a callback by simply appending `@` to a function name to create a function handle, **these two arguments are automatically passed to the function**.

You can instead craft your anonymous function to accept two input arguments and call `uigetdir` with no input arguments, effectively ignoring the default callback inputs.

```
set(hb, 'Callback', @(s,e)uigetdir())
```

If you want to pass a start path and a title you can pass those to `uigetdir` from within the anonymous function.

```
set(hb, 'Callback', @(s,e)uigetdir('mystartpath', 'mytitle'))
```