# MATLAB callback function: undefined function?

Tags: matlab, oop, event-listener

I have a button group with 3 radio buttons inside, as well as a display section.

The effect I want is that once choosing a radio button, the display section changes as well.

I implement it using a class, and add the `SelectionChangedFcn` when creating those components:

```
app.ControlButtonGroup.SelectionChangedFcn = {@controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged, app}
```

I define the function `controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(obj, eventData, app)` at the same file where the createComponents.m function file is saved.

But when I click a different radio, error messages are as following:

> Undefined function 'controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged' for input
>   arguments of type 'matlab.ui.container.ButtonGroup'. Error while
>   evaluating ButtonGroup SelectionChangedFcn

I also declare the `controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged` function as a private method in my class.

The controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged function is as following:

```
function controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(obj, eventData, app)
% Update display section as the radio button in control section is changed

    %new = app.ControlButtonGroup.NewValue;
    new = obj.SelectedObject.String;
    switch new
        case 'Transfer Path'
            % display the transfer path
            imagesc(app.curImage,'Parent',app.DisplayPath);
            app.DisplayPath.Visible = 'off';
        case 'Store'
            % display the store text
            text(curStore,'Parent',app.DisplayPath);
        case 'Mill'
            % Display the Mill text
            text(curMill,'Parent',app.DisplayPath);
    end
end
```

The part of that defined in class is as :

```
methods (Access = private)

    % Create UIFigure and components
    createComponents(app);

    % Callback function for Control Button Group Selection Changed
    controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(obj, eventData, app);

end
```

And The part related to that in createComponents function is:

```
    app.ControlButtonGroup = uibuttongroup(app.UIFigure);
    app.ControlButtonGroup.Title = 'Control';
    app.ControlButtonGroup.FontSize = 16;
    app.ControlButtonGroup.Units = 'Normalized';
    app.ControlButtonGroup.Position = [0.45 0.75 0.45 0.2];
    app.ControlButtonGroup.SelectionChangedFcn = {@controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged,app};
```

Why does it say that my function is undefined?

UPDATE:
I have gone through some other demos, and changed the callback as app.ControlButtonGroup.SelectionChangedFcn = @(h, e)controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(app). And define(also prototype) it just as controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(app). It works then. so I guess the problem should be about the number of parameters, but I still don't find much detailed information on that. Any hints are appreciated!!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your function name? Also it would be helpful for you to post the actual file.

Comment: Yes, I copied the name just in case I didn't make typos. And I just double checked it

Comment: I am wondering if it might be problem to call a private method from another private one?

Comment: When I type "which controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged" in MATLAB command line, it shows C:\Users\mxie\Desktop\AnalyticalEngine(OOP)\@DisplayPanel\controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged.m  % DisplayPanel method. So it was defined and should be recognized.

Comment: Added an answer and description below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to supply the object as the first argument to the function so that MATLAB knows to look for it as a method of `app`.

```
app.ControlButtonGroup.SelectionChangedFcn = @(s,e)controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(app, s, e);

% Or this way which implicitly passes the two input parameters

app.ControlButtonGroup.SelectionChangedFcn = @app.controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged;
```

Then your method would look like this

```
function controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(obj, source, event)
```

If you don't need the `source` (the handle to the control button group) or `event` (the eventdata associated with the selection event), then you can have your callback "ignore" these second and third inputs by doing something like

```
app.ControlButtonGroup.SelectionChangedFcn = @(s,e)app.controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged();
```

And your method would look like

```
function controlBtnGroupSelectionChanged(app)
```

Comment: Thx! What parameters should I define then. controBtnGroupSelection(app), or just nothing?

Comment: @MichelleShieh It depends on whether you need the first two parameters or not. I have updated with an explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot! You perfectly solved my problem! Just wondering why we need the (s,e) before the calling? Prestate something? Is there any concept explanation/documentation about them?

Comment: @MichelleShieh All `uicontrol` callbacks automatically pass two input arguments to the callback. The `@(s,e)` accepts two callbacks but then doesn't pass any of them onto your function. More info in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38855302/670206)